# codeigniter, ion_autho logout() session error

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

Recently i implemented ion_auth into my hmvc system.
Now the problem is when i logout from my cms, logout is working, but before is destroying the session is showing me those errors:

> Undefined index: session_id
>
> Undefined index: ip_address
>
> Undefined index: user_agent
>
> .....

now i don't know what is next lines of error cause is just for 1 second and then is destroying the session.
Could this be a security issue ? Because if i turn off development mode it doesn't show anymore.
Any suggestions how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer this problem by myself as nobody willed to help me :)
so that was the causing problem

```
line 102-103
//log the user out
function logout()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Logout";

    //log the user out
    $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();

    //redirect them to the login page
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
    redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
}
```

and I changed it to:

```
//log the user out
function logout()
{
    if($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        $this->ion_auth->logout();
        redirect('admin/login', 'refresh');
    }

}
```

source: I tested myself and is working just fine :)